# How can i get max date value

Tags: sql

Here's my table

[image: Here's my table]

School (`schcd`) column has different values on different dates. How can I get last updated value?

```
 select distinct distcd,blkcd,schcd,is_correct_info,entry_date 
 from adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv 
 having max(entry_date) order by schcd
```

Comment: i tried select distinct distcd,blkcd,schcd,is_correct_info,entry_date from adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv  having max(entry_date)
 order by schcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group by` the first 3 columns and get the last date:

```
select 
  distcd,
  blkcd,
  schcd,
  1 is_correct_info,
  max(entry_date) entry_date 
from adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv 
where is_correct_info = 1
group by
  distcd,
  blkcd,
  schcd
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a where and subquery, and if you want only the row with is_correct_info = 1 add a proper filter clause

```
select distinct 
    distcd,
    blkcd,
    schcd,
    is_correct_info,
    entry_date 
from 
    adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv 
where 
    entry_date = (select max(entry_date) 
                  from  adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv) 
    and is_correct_info = 1
order by 
    schcd
```

Or an inner join on the subquery

```
select distinct 
    distcd,
    blkcd,
    schcd,
    is_correct_info,
    entry_date 
from 
    adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv 
inner join 
    (select max(entry_date) max_date
     from adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv) t on t.max_date = adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv.entry_date 
                                          and is_correct_info = 1
order by 
    schcd
```

Comment: suppose that  schcd=2001 get value in is_correct_info=1 on  25-03-2019 and it has is_correct_info=0 on 01-01-2019 , how can i get schcd=2001 has is_correct_info=1 on  25-03-2019 this value

Comment: I'm not in your data  ..  add  a proper (clear) data sample and your expected . result  ..

Comment: sir i have uploaded image you can see it, in that picture schcd=20010101118 have is_info_correct=0 on entry_date=2018-09-09 18:30:00 but it is updated on 2019-01-18 18:30:00, just i want that schcd =20010101118 have  data on 2019-01-18 18:30:00

Comment: your explanation is not clear anyway i have added  a filter for and  is_correct_info = 1  .. answer  updated

Answer (score 0):

you just need to order by entry_date descending

```
select distinct distcd,blkcd,schcd,is_correct_info,entry_date 
 from adhoc_teacher_attendance_prv 
order by entry_date desc
```

in method expression syntax i would use .FirstOrDefault(), it should be select top(1), to get only the first

to filter for schcd use

```
where schcd = 123
```